# AAS Refresh Issue: The credentials provided for the SQL source are invalid

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-analysis-services

We have been trying to refresh AAS(full process) from SSMS with AAD authentication and from Azure runbooks with Service Principal authentication.
But, we are getting below error in both the scenario:

**Invoke-ProcessASDatabase : Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'The credentials provided for
the SQL source are invalid. (Source at "synapse sql pool server/db name".). The exception was
raised by the IDbCommand interface.
Technical Details:
RootActivityId: 349070d5-09f3-4496-9f2b-69203c485e04
Date (UTC): 4/20/2021 7:54:43 PM

The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.
The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.
The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.
The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.
The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.
The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.**

for Azure runbook method, we have followed the below link, but getting above error.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-refresh-azure-automation][1]

Our Source for AAS is Synapse Sql Pool.

How to resolve above error. Let me know if more information is required.